# Scala Higher Order Function Little Confused

Tags: scala, functional-programming, currying, higher-order-functions

I was running the below Scala code in Worksheet:

```
package src.com.sudipta.week2.coursera
import scala.math.abs
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object FixedPoint {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  val tolerance = 0.0001                          //> tolerance  : Double = 1.0E-4
  def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double): Boolean = {
    abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance
  }                                               //> isCloseEnough: (x: Double, y: Double)Boolean
  def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double): Double = {
    @tailrec
    def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
      val next = f(guess)
      if (isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
      else iterate(next)
    }
    iterate(firstGuess)
  }                                               //> fixedPoint: (f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double)Double

  def myFixedPoint = fixedPoint(x => 1 + x / 2)(1)//> myFixedPoint: => Double
  myFixedPoint                                    //> res0: Double = 1.999755859375

  def squareRoot(x: Double) = fixedPoint(y => (y + x / y) / 2)(1)
                                                  //> squareRoot: (x: Double)Double
  squareRoot(2)                                   //> res1: Double = 1.4142135623746899

  def calculateAverate(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) = (x + f(x)) / 2
                                                  //> calculateAverate: (f: Double => Double)(x: Double)Double
  def myNewSquareRoot(x: Double): Double = fixedPoint(calculateAverate(y => x / y))(1)
                                                  //> myNewSquareRoot: (x: Double)Double
  myNewSquareRoot(2)                              //> res2: Double = 1.4142135623746899
}
```

What is making me confused are:

- Scala worksheet is showing below for my fixedPoint function

> fixedPoint: (f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double)Double

What is this? Is this function type/ function definition or I am missing the term? 
Basically how I can explain this function in English?

- Scala worksheet is showing below for my calculateAverate function

> calculateAverate: (f: Double => Double)(x: Double)Double

But it looks to me the return type of my function is Double, but I was expecting Double => Double. The reason is I am going to use this with fixedPoint which expects Double => Double like below:

> def myNewSquareRoot(x: Double): Double = fixedPoint(calculateAverate(y
>   => x / y))(1)

Please help me to understand Higher Order Function / Currying more clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```
def fixedPoint (f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double):Double
```

is a function definition which takes two arguments:

1. a function "f" which takes a parameter of type `Double` which returns a `Double` and
2. a `Double` value named "firstGuess"

and returns a `Double`. The separation of the single parameters into their own parenthesis groups allows the function to be used in currying:

```
def mySqrtCalc(x:Double)(firstGuess:Double):Double = {...}

val mySqrtFunc = mySqrtCalc(2.0) _

val v = mySqrtFunc(1) // parameter firstGuess is set to 1
```

Beside the ability for currying, this is equivalent to the uncurried version

```
def fixedPoint (f: Double => Double,firstGuess: Double):Double
```

which might look more familiar to you.

The result of the `calculateAverate` is a Double because you add up the result of applying  the passed function f to x with x which gives you a `Double` because f is a function `Double => Double`.

You use `calculateAverate` method in a curried way in your `myNewSquareRoot` method body, by giving only the first of both parameters in first place and omitting the second one, which is taken from the from the outer `fixedPoint` method. Omitting the second parameter of `calculateAverate` gives you a method `Double=>Double` as it is required by the `fixedPoint` method.

You might insert some `println(s"<methodname> value=$value")` to observe the execution flow and understand the method call order.

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation. I think in the example you provided you missed one part def mySqrtCalc(x:Double)(firstGuess: Double):Double = {...}.. right?

Answer (score 4):

```
fixedPoint: (f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double)Double
```

The task here is to find fixed points of functions and the application of the task will be to our well known **square root with Newton's method**

**Square Root by Newton's method:**

*`Calculates the square root of parameter x`*

```
def sqrt(x: Double): Double = ...
```

The classical way to achieve this is by successive approximations using Newton’s method.

To compute sqrt(x):

1. Start with an initial estimate y (let’s pick y = 1).
2. Repeatedly improve the estimate by taking the mean of y and x/y.

Example:   `x=2`

```
  Estimation               Quotient                    Mean
    1                       2/1=2                       1.5
   1.5                      2/1.5=1.333                1.4167
  1.4167                    2/1.4167=1.4118            1.4142
  1.4142 so on
```

**First**, define a function which computes one iteration step

```
def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)
```

**Second**, define a function improve to improve an estimate and a test to check for terminatation:

```
def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) =
(guess + x / guess) / 2
def isGoodEnough(guess: Double, x: Double) =
abs(guess * guess - x) < 0.001
```

**Third**, define the sqrt function:

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = srqtIter(1.0, x)
```

**using your Fixedpoint function we also calculating square root of a number**

first see what is fixed point:

A `number x` is called a **fixed point of a function f** if `f(x) = x`

For some functions f we can locate the fixed points by starting with an initial estimate and then by applying f in a repetitive way.

```
x, f(x), f(f(x))
```

This leads to the following function for finding a fixed point:

```
val tolerance = 0.0001
def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double) =
abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance
def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
val next = f(guess)
if (isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
else iterate(next)
}
iterate(firstGuess)
}
```

In this formulation,`fixedPoint` is a function which returns another function, namely the specialized function `iterate`

here `fixedPoint`

```
def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double)
```

the function `fixedPoint` is applied to the function `f: Double => Double`. The resulting
function is then applied to the second argument

```
(firstGuess: Double)
```

This notation is possible because function application associates to the left. That is,
if args1 and args2 are argument lists, then `f(args1)(args2)` is equivalent to `(f(args1))args2`

In your program first argument is function that  take input type is Double and return type is Double and then apply this function to the guess

**reformulation of the square root function.**

Let’s start with a specification of sqrt:

```
sqrt(x) = the y such that y*y = x
        = the y such that y = x / y
```

Hence, sqrt(x) is a fixed point of the function `y => x / y`. This suggests that

```
sqrt(x)
```

can be computed by fixed point iteration:

```
def sqrt(x: double) = fixedPoint(y => x / y)(1.0)
```

this is a long answer but i think it will help you to understand the concept